# C++ interface declaration - returning vector of pointers or vector of objects

Tags: c++, interface

My problem is related to declaring interfaces - classes with pure virtual methods. The best way to explain this problem is with an example. Though this problem isn't limited to this specific example.

Let's say that I'm trying to make a somewhat generic interface for a range search algorithm.
Each added value will have some position (in 2D, 3D, ...) and some other information, which the user can change (whether it belongs to some group of other values, etc.).
The basic requirements would be:

1. Storing values - *Add()*
2. Getting stored values with the ability to change them - *Get()* (not really a getter, since you can change the values, but bear with me)
3. Getting stored values close to another value - *RangeQuery()*

Interface would look like this:

```
template <typename T>
class RangeSearchInterface // ... Omitted virtual dtor, move ctor, etc.
{
public:
    virtual void Add(const T & value) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<T> & Get() = 0;
    virtual std::vector<T *> & RangeQuery(const T & value) = 0;
};
```

Now let's implement 2 RangeSearch algorithms: Brute force algorithm and a somewhat better algorithm, which adds values into chunks with specific size (omitted) and limits the number of comparisons which it does. We don't want to have some unnecessary overhead or be space inefficient just to conform to this interface.

Brute force:

```
template <typename T>
class BruteForceRangeSearch : public RangeSearchInterface<T>
{
public:
    void Add(const T & value) override {
        _added.push_back(value);
    };

    std::vector<T> & Get() override {
        return _added; // Simply return the vector of added values
    };

    /// Note: Calling Add() invalidates the pointers returned by this method
    std::vector<T *> & RangeQuery(const T & value) override {
        _rangeQuery.clear();
        for (auto & anotherValue : _added) { // Omitted InRange method - returns whether or not 2 values are close to each other
            if (InRange(value, anotherValue)) _rangeQuery.push_back(&anotherValue);
        }
        return _rangeQuery;
    };
private:
    std::vector<T> _added;        // Values added by user
    std::vector<T *> _rangeQuery; // Returning pointers to _added
};
```

Somewhat better algorithm (pay attention to Get() and Get_Better() methods):

```
template <typename T>
class SomewhatBetterRangeSearch : public RangeSearchInterface<T>
{
public:
    void Add(const T & value) override { // Omitted CalculateChunkIndex
        _chunks.at(CalculateChunkIndex(value)).push_back(value);
    };

    std::vector<T> & Get() override {
        _getAdded_1.clear();
        for (auto & chunks : _chunks) { // Go through each added chunk
            for (auto & anotherValue : _added) { // Go through each value in chunk
                _getAdded_1.push_back(anotherValue); // Oops! Creating a copy, that could be expensive and/or space ineffecient. We could do better...
            }
            _getAdded_1.push_back()
        }
        return _getAdded_1; // Oops! We are returning a reference to another vector! Changing values in this vector won't have any effect!
    };

    std::vector<T *> & Get_Better() override {
        _getAdded_2.clear();
        for (auto & chunks : _chunks) { // Go through each added chunk
            for (auto & anotherValue : _added) { // Go through each value in chunk
                _getAdded_2.push_back(&anotherValue); // Good. Store a pointer. No unnecessary copy
            }
        }
        return _getAdded_2; // Returning pointers to objects :(
    };

    /// Note: Calling Add() after call to this method invalidates the pointers
    std::vector<T *> & RangeQuery(const T & value) override {
        _rangeQuery.clear();
        auto closeChunks = GetChunksCloseTo(value);
        for (auto & closeChunk : closeChunks) {
            for (auto & anotherValue : closeChunk) { // Same thing as in brute force algorithm, but we have limited the range
                if (InRange(value, anotherValue)) _rangeQuery.push_back(&anotherValue);
            }
        }
        return _rangeQuery;
    };
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> _chunks; // Values added by user split into chunks
    std::vector<T *> _rangeQuery;        // Returning pointers to values in _chunks
    std::vector<T> _getAdded_1;          // Returning copies of values from chunks in _chunks
    std::vector<T *> _getAdded_2;        // Returning pointers to values from chunks in _chunks
};
```

As you can see, we can't make a Get() method which conforms to the interface. We can't return a reference to the vector of values, since changing these values wouldn't have any effect. Returning a vector of pointers would be much better.
Maybe we could change the interface...

```
// RangeSearchInterface ...
virtual std::vector<T *> & Get() = 0;
```

but that would mean we have to create another vector in BruteForceRangeSearch, iterate through the vector of added values and store each pointer. Overhead to already (in some cases) inefficient algorithm.
Maybe putting this return value in a template could solve this issue... but then another obvious problem would be benchmarking/testing these classes - if I want to simply switch between these 2 algorithms, I'd have to change all the . to -> .

Another example would be:

```
virtual const std::vector<const T *> & Get() = 0;
// vs
virtual const std::vector<T> & Get() = 0;
```

... in this case, we aren't even giving the user the ability to change the values, but because of optimization we would like to return pointers instead of objects.

This is a very specific example, but I'm challenged with this problem very often while declaring interfaces.
Hopefully you see where I'm going with all of this:

- How do you decide whether you return a vector of pointers to objects or vector of objects in these cases?
- Is it even worth it to make an interface for something like this?
- and probably the answer I'm looking for the most: How do you **not** get to a point, where you will have to deal with this problem?

Comment: `virtual void Visit(std::function<void(T&)>) = 0;` Then the implementation isn't constrained by the interface in its choice of the data structures.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's...very simple, yet, if I'm not mistaken, it basically solves most of my use cases, that I could've think of. Thank you very much, I'll definitely try and use this more often.